# ntlm authentication error in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ntlm

I have a problem with ***ntlm authentication***, all is good however after a few hours when my application is open, this window opens :

[image]

What makes it happen? How can I make it stop?

edit:
I am using the express-ntlm module,
I am using it like this:

```
ntlm = require('express-ntlm')
app.use(ntlm({
    "domain":"myDomain",
    "domaincontroller":["myDomainController"]
}))
```

Comment: Could you provide some sources? How do you configure `ntlm` and which modules do you use?

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: is it maple-ntlm or ntlm. can you share the link of the package in the question

Comment: it is express-ntlm, i got confused with something else.. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ntlm this is the package im using

Comment: There is a timeout of 5000 seconds on the connection ([source](https://github.com/einfallstoll/express-ntlm/blob/1b6d50b76074a12a0bbbcfce0e220d881458067d/lib/NTLM_Proxy.js#L25)). You can possibly adjust that.

Comment: is there a way to remove the timeout?